# Cast String to int and use in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert string field and use for Where clause.Am getting exception like this please help to find the wrong thing.

```
select * from student 
where (cast (nvl(linerevnum,'0') as int)) = 1
```

linerevnum is varchar2

Exception :
invalid number

Comment: this is because, some row, has a non numeric value stored in this column.

Comment: even after checking null also same thing happens.Thank you for your reply.Updated the Question.

Comment: he never said null, he said non numeric values... Read the compatibility here http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compare only when is numeric

```
select * from student 
where 
  (
  case when ISNUMERIC( linerevnum ) 
  then cast (linerevnum as int)
  else null
  end  ) = 1
```

or simple:

```
select * from student 
linerevnum = '1'
```

Comment: GOOGLERS!!! Change 'int' to 'SIGNED', 'UNSIGNED' or 'DECIMAL(xx)' bare int is not valid in MySQL CAST()

Comment: @webLacky3rdClass, MYSQL? Who talks about MYSQL? It's [oracle cast](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) function. Is GOOGLERS a kind of insult?? UNREADERS, read tags before write comments ;)

Comment: This was was still high in the search for MySQL CAST, so it seemed appropriate to have the same for MySQL. Tag or not it is still what comes up in a search. If Googlers is some sort of insult, well, then I think, most people reading this will chant curses at me {"May your servers UPS fail!","May a buffer overflow come upon you!","Let the NSA know your private keys!"} that sort of thing ;)

Comment: @webLacky3rdClass,  Ooooook! Now I understand. Just advice to people who comes from google! Ok. Thanks!