# [PHP]Can you get this sorted by DESC

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know how to put my list in DESC order.

I tried many things but I still have this order:

```
function release_year(){
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `meta_value` FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta` WHERE `meta_key`='release_year'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
return $results;
```

This is what I get

```
2016
2015
2014
1988
2001
2010
1998
...
```

Comment: _"I tried many things"_ Like what? Have you tried using `ORDER BY`?

Comment: `... WHERE `meta_key`='release_year' order by 1 desc`

Answer (score 1):

```
function release_year(){
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `meta_value` FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta` WHERE `meta_key`='release_year' ORDER BY meta_value DESC";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
return $results;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you use `order by`, the next problem you will run into, is that you must cast it as an integer.

See: [Cast String to int and use in Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654183/cast-string-to-int-and-use-in-where-clause)

You must do `order by meta_value` first and then follow the link.