# Could not check value within two column using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing one issue. I need to check value which should present within two column values using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

```
    id      zip_from               zip_to

     1        751001                751030
```

**db_postcode:**

```
$post_code='751010';
$sql="select * from db_postcode where zip_from >='".$post_code."' and zip_to='".$post_code."'";
$sqlpin=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlpin) > 0) {
    $data=array("status"=>"Success","msg"=>"Product is available for this postcode");
}else{
    $data=array("status"=>"Failed","msg"=>"Product is not available for this postcode");
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Here I am getting the message `{"status":"Failed","msg":"Product is not available for this postcode"}`  which is wrong because code `751010` is present within `751001-751030`. Here I need to check the user given value should be present within that two column.

Comment: Can you share the exact column definitions? Is `zip_from` a `INT` column? And why do you think that this is related to PHP?

Comment: You have `zip_to = `, but i think you need `zip_to <=`.

Comment: @NicoHaase : both column is `varchar`.

Comment: @Cynical : No as per you also not working.

Comment: Mind the SQL injection

Comment: As @Cynical writes - Right now you are checking for a postnumber that is above 751001 but excactly 751030. meaning that only 751030 will work

Comment: also - since it is varchars, I am not sure that you can use it as pure numbers? why are they not intergers? if sql considers them as strings, can you use a numeric value to check it?

Comment: I guess you can since `'BALL' < 'water'` will return true

Comment: You have to cast the column and then compare the values like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654296/7296317

Answer (score 1):

Your compare is written the wrong way around, what you want is to check that `$post_code` is between `zip_from` and `zip_to`:

```
$sql="select * from db_postcode where '$post_code' between zip_from and zip_to";
```

Note that this will only work if all `zip_from`, `zip_to` and `$post_code` values are the same length, otherwise you will run into issues that in a string compare, `2 > 100000`. If they are not the same length, you should cast them to integer to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Your query would should be this:

```
$sql="select * from db_postcode where ".$post_code." BETWEEN zip_from and zip_to";
```

Comment: I have already tried this but same issue. Let me to remind you both column has datatype varchar.

Comment: Please explain **why** it should be like this and which exact changes were needed